# Tricking Outlook into thinking my submitted infopath form is not XML

Tags: xml, email, infopath

I've inherited an application that generates InfoPath forms. I'm required to add functionality so that the forms can be submitted by email whilst offline. The idea is that the forms can be filled in offline, and then sent via email, and then processed by another application that checks the submission inbox.

Unfortunately I have to use WEBDav code on the server to check the email inbox which is equivalent to Outlook Web Access. OWA blocks xml files or strips the xml out of the file. I've tried setting the name of the attachment programmatically to another extension but that doesnt work, Outlook must read all files and if it finds XML tags, takes it out of the document.

What I did try was changing the first line out of the form and submitting that. I changed the `<?xml version="1.0"` to `<?xsl version="1.0"` . It worked! It seems so long as Outlook doesn't find the 'xml' string then it doesnt think its an xml document.

Currently I am submitting the form programmatically using a button and some JS.

Is there any way I can modify the raw data before it is submitted? Ie, changing the opening XML tag to XSL. Or perhaps change the encoding? Or obfuscate the file or anything?

In summary, I need to trick outlook into thinking the submitted form is not XML. The solution must be self contained within an XSN.

edit: using InfoPath 2003. Not sure of the Exchange version but I think its 2003 also.

Comment: Have you tried: [KB555001: Outlook Web Access - Configure Attachment Blocking](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555001)

Comment: We do not get paid for answers, there are other sites for that. Close++

Comment: See the blocking attachments heading here:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;830827#XSLTH3277121124120121120120

Comment: I'm sorry - is there some problem offering money because I really need a solution to this quickly? I could wait a few days and use StackOverflow bounty points. I just figured cash would be a better motivator. Please point me to the section in the terms and conditions where it says this is not allowed.

Comment: I am working within a corporate SOE environment. I can not modify Exchanve server settings or client registry settings.

Answer (score 0):

can you encrypt the file into something outlook can't see - a binary file in other words? Sounds a bit like steganography (hidden messages) but what if you encode the data into some other binary object - like an image perhaps?.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am trying to do. I just need to be able to create the file from within InfoPath. Just modifying the raw xml to remove the xml tag is enough...I'm looking for a method to do this.

Comment: I should note that something like steganography is a bit over the top. I just need to modify the XML tag to XMS or XSM or something equally meaningless so the attachment parser doesnt recognise it as xml.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this before and worked very well.  though it was a few years ago now.  It worked against Exchange 2003.  not sure it works against Exchange 2008 though.

```
Public Function retrieve() As Boolean
    Dim allOK As Boolean = True
    Dim rec As ADODB.Record
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim url As String
    Dim sql As String
    Dim iMessage As CDO.Message = New CDO.MessageClass
    Dim numAttachments As Integer
    Dim DeleteEmail As Boolean = False
    Dim EmailsFound As Integer = 0
    Try

        rec = New ADODB.Record
        rs = New ADODB.Recordset

        url = "Url to outlook web access inbox"

        rec.Open(url, , ConnectModeEnum.adModeReadWrite, , , AppSettings(MAILBOX_USERNAME), AppSettings(MAILBOX_PASSWORD))

        ' Build the SQL query for the messages.
        sql = "select "
        sql = sql & " ""urn:schemas:mailheader:subject"""
        sql = sql & ", ""urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment"""
        sql = sql & ", ""DAV:href"""
        sql = sql & ", ""urn:schemas:httpmail:from"""
        sql = sql & " from scope ('shallow traversal of "
        sql = sql & """" & url & """" & "') "

        If IsDebugEnabled Then log.Debug("retreieveEmails() - Opening Recordset:" & sql)


        ' Open the recordset.
        rs.Open(sql, rec.ActiveConnection, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenUnspecified, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

        If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
            rs.MoveFirst()
            ' Loop through all of the messages in the recordset

            Do Until rs.EOF
                EmailsFound += 1
                DeleteEmail = False


                If Not rs.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:subject").Value Is System.DBNull.Value Then
                    iMessage.DataSource.Open(System.Convert.ToString(rs.Fields("DAV:href").Value), rec.ActiveConnection, ADODB.ConnectModeEnum.adModeRead, ADODB.RecordCreateOptionsEnum.adFailIfNotExists, ADODB.RecordOpenOptionsEnum.adOpenSource, "", "")
                    'Check that the Attachment is an XML file
                    For Each objAttachment As CDO.IBodyPart In iMessage.Attachments
                        If CStr(objAttachment.FileName & "").ToUpper.EndsWith(".XML") Then
                            'Save the Attachment off
                            objAttachment.SaveToFile(IO.Path.Combine(AppSettings(TEMP_IN_DIR), objAttachment.FileName))
                            DeleteEmail = True
                        End If
                    Next
                End If

                If DeleteEmail Then
                    delete(rs.Fields("DAV:href").Value)
                End If
                rs.MoveNext()
            Loop
        Else
            ' No Emails Found
        End If


        Return True
    Catch e As Exception
        'Log the error
        Return False
    Finally
        Try
            rs.Close()
        Catch
        End Try
        Try
            rs = Nothing
        Catch
        End Try
        Try
            rec.Close()
        Catch
        End Try
        Try
            rec = Nothing
        Catch
        End Try
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your input but I dont think i'll try it, I ended up telling my manager it just wasnt possible.